# Syntax error in LocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Error screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
 if (_locationManager == nil) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;

        _locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization; // this is OK with warning
        _locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization(); // this is giving me error
    }
```

I am fairly new to iOS development, so not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Hi Volleyball, are you developing in Objective-C? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Objective-C is still pretty awesome, btw.

Comment: @MacUserT I am ashamed of asking this, is this the `Objective-C` code? I thought it is `Swift`.

Comment: @Volleyball, although Aaron thinks Objective-C is still awesome, it looks like you are mixing both in the code.

Comment: @Aaron yes my code complies and it works fine on commenting the 2 lines. But how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Yeah, MacUserT is spot on. Your Obj-c function call to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` seems off.

Comment: I think you want `[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` ...

Comment: @Aaron it worked, many many thanks, please write it in answer and I am happy to accept it. And MacuserT I will upvote yours too if you write for swift. Thanks you guys again, love both of you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C, I think what you want is to properly send the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` message to your `_locationManager` instance, like so:

`[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`

And as MacUserT mentioned it appears you're blending both Swift and Objective-C style code. I'm not certain how your original snippet compiled, though. Homework for me, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following when developing in Swift:

```
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
```

This should work if you have created a project with the language selected Swift.
[image]

If you develop in Objective-C I think the best way is:

```
let locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager delegate] = self;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I am sorry I can't accept both the answers, but I upvoted yours too.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Good luck.